# CASE WHEN THEN with subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I try to do a switch like c# in sql or if with differents conditions.

I use that but it don't work at all :

it's for a stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Mystoredprocedure]
@Value INT
AS 
BEGIN

       SET NOCOUNT ON;
CASE

WHEN @Value = 0
THEN SELECT * FROM mytable1


WHEN @Value = 1
THEN SELECT * FROM mytable2

WHEN @Value = 2
THEN SELECT * FROM mytable3

END
```

But it doesn't work, i search examples but i don't find what i want really.

I try too :

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Mystoredprocedure]
    @Value INT
    AS
    BEGIN
          SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF @Value = 0
    BEGIN
         SELECT * FROM MyTable1
    END

    ELSE IF @Value = 1
    BEGIN
         SELECT * FROM MyTable2
    END

    ELSE IF @Value = 2
    BEGIN 
         SELECT * FROM Mytable3
    END

END
```

Have you the solution to fix that ? Thanks !

Comment: What problem do you have with the `if` solution?

Comment: It say that there is a systax error before every if

Comment: `CASE` is T-SQL is an **expression** - it can return one of several values. But it is **NOT** a flow-control statement like in C# - you'll need to use `IF ... THEN ....` for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Mystoredprocedure] (@Value INT)
AS 
BEGIN

    IF @Value = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM mytable1
        END
    ELSE IF @Value = 1
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM mytable2
        END
    ELSE IF @Value = 2
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM mytable3
        END

END
```

If I get this right, the problem is that you have a variable in your query, but you don't pass a value to it. You declare it, and it's empty. With this way, if you call the query

```
EXEC [dbo].[Mystoredprocedure] 1
```

It should select from mytable 2, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it says that there syntax error with CASE and every WHEN

Comment: @Julien698 I have updated your answer. ````CASE WHEN```` is used when you are in a ````SELECT```` statement. Normal ````IF ... ELSE```` conditions can be used in procs, etc.

Comment: that the good code, but it don't work with the else, i've to put if everywhere and not "else if" for the others conditions

Comment: Don't know what can be causing it, I have tested it and it was working as expected.

Comment: Yes it's strange because it is the good syntax i don't understand why it do that !

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution, it's easy. I've just to remove the else before the if and it works !

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MystoredProcedure]
(@Value INT)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;



IF @Value = 0
BEGIN   
     SELECT * FROM mytable1
END

IF @Value = 1
BEGIN
     SELECT * FROM mytable2
END

IF @Value = 2
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM mytable3  
END

IF @Value = 3
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM mytable4
END

END
```